# How to fix Internet Explorer 10 after iMacros plugin installation?

Tags: uninstall, internet-explorer-10

I wanted to install iMacros on my ie 10 (win 8). After unsuccessful trial, as i launch the browser a popup appears with the message: "The IE program does not work. A problem arose that led to closing the program. Click to close".

[image]

I click and browser closes. 
The case turned that i cannot uninstall ie from windows. 
As i've downloaded and tried to install new version it replied that there is already an ie version installed. 
How to break thru?

Answer (score 0):

I've just deleted the ie 10 thru Start board. Then i uninstalled iMacros and afterwards i've installed everything again. Now it works.